# Invalid number of parameters xcopy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, xcopy

I am creating a pipeline script in my jenkins server(windows). I am trying to copy from SOURCE to DESTINATION using following command.
I am getting an error 'invalid number of parameters xcopy /O /X /E /H /K' when  run the jenkins job.
What is the issue in the command below.

```
xcopy \fileshares\myproject\builds\MyWelcomeApp\org D:\MyWelcomeApp\org /O /X /E /H /K
```

Comment: Are these file paths the actual paths to the files? Or do the actual paths contain spaces ? If so, Please surround the file paths with `"` (double-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with like this?

```
xcopy  $ProjectDir\fonts  $FrontEndFilesLocation\$AssemblyName\fonts /E /i /Y /C
```